# jQuery UI Autocomplete not populating dropdown

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Trying to get jquery AutoComplete to return and populate it's dropdown.  The input and call looks like this:

```
<input id="user_login" name="user[login]" size="22" type="text" value="" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#user_login, #user_group_name').autocomplete({
      source: '/users.js'
    });    
  });
</script>
```

The URL string that gets called is:

```
http://localhost:3000/users.js?term=user
```

The return from users.js looks like this:

```
[{"id":1802,"login":"some.user"},{"id":3882,"login":"some.other_user"},{"id":2024,"login":"user"}]
```

The autocomplete seems to interpret some of the return: it populates the autocomplete UL with three LIs, but they are all empty.  If I search for something else, the appropriate amount of empty LIs is created.  I've verified the JSON return with JSONLint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my return.  Autocomplete wanted a single item per term, like so:

```
[{"login":"some.user"}]
```