# jQuery autocomplete menu not populated using Flask

Tags: jquery, flask, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been flipping tables over this for days now and really hope someone can help.

I have a simple Bootstrap web form that takes freetype text and adds the entries to a MySQL database table. To help users avoid typos or duplicative terms for the same thing, I'd like to implement the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) to suggest entries the DB table already has.

Using `app.logger.debug()` and `console.log()`, I can see that the DB call is successful and that I get existing DB entries in an array `["item1", "item2", ..]` on the frontend.

**The problem** is that, while typing, the form field only shows a few pixels of the autocomplete menu, without content.

I'm using Bootstrap
`stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css`
and jQuery / jQuery UI
`code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`, `code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, `code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js`

JS:

```
$(":text").focus( function() {
    var input_field = encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('id'))
    var dataString  = 'input_field=' + input_field

    $.getJSON('/availability_autosuggest'
        , dataString
        , function (data) {
            console.log(input_field)
            console.log(data)
            $('#' + input_field).autocomplete({
                                        minLength: 2
                                        , source: data});
        }
    )
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

@app.route('/availability_autosuggest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def availability_autosuggest():
    db_entries = []
    input_field     = request.args.get('input_field')
    # returns list of table entries ["item1", "item2", ..]
    db_entries.append(DBOperations().query_table('table_name', column_name=input_field))

    return jsonify(db_entries)
```

What am I missing?!

The following posts seem to be related but the suggestions didn't solve my problem:

- [Autocomplete using Flask, Jquery , Javascript, MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357235/autocomplete-using-flask-jquery-javascript-mysql)
- [Using jQuery autocomplete with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365821/using-jquery-autocomplete-with-flask)
- [Flask AJAX Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310644/flask-ajax-autocomplete)
- [Jquery autocomplete not populate list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878032/jquery-autocomplete-not-populate-list)
- [jQuery UI Autocomplete not populating dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762518/jquery-ui-autocomplete-not-populating-dropdown)